# How can I install different versions of Android?

Tags: android

I installed the Android SDK. When i ran it I can only see Andriod 4.2.2 (API 17).

Why don't I see all the API options? (e.g. API 11, 12, 13, 14)

Do I need to install something else?

This is the SDK manager log:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Done loading packages.
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Done loading packages.
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Done loading packages.
```

Comment: Go->Windows->preference->Android there you can see all the version of Android , if not find any thing. go->windows->SDK Manager install Android version

Comment: How I can download more options ?

Comment: I can see only one version in windows->SDK Manager install Android version

Comment: Are you running under windows, linux or Mac? 
All the errors like "Failed to fetch URL ..." make me think that you just have troubles updating the sdk via the sdk manager

Comment: in eclipse download Android SDK manager

Comment: I am running under windows, I just download the SDK

Comment: once try to reinstall it

Comment: I tried to do it but it didn't work does it the right web http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ?

Comment: I just copy the SDK Do I need to do any install ?How I can add them manually ?

Comment: if you r having SDK file of Android version..then go to SDK file folder in then you will get sample folder past there and restart

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27407/discussion-between-kirankumar-and-user1365697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your sdk manager.
2. Click "**Packages**" from left top.
3. Click "**Show Updates/New Packages**"
4. You should see a list of Android versions. Click which you want and then click "**Install X packages**" from right bottom.

x is the counter of files.

Comment: I still see only one version of Android and I want to see all the versions. I need to add version 4.02

Comment: I understand. But if you want to add a version, you should see all versions at sdk manager. And i really can not get the reason. Did you try to download sdk again ?